# Putting an int in an int pointer gives runtime error in C .

Tags: c, pointers

The following [code](http://ideone.com/5Zu8Zm) works fine in ideone but it gives a runtime error in codeblocks IDE . Is my IDE broken or is there any programming language specific issues .

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int *pointer;
    int num = 45;
    *pointer = num;
    printf("pointer points to value %d", *pointer);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `pointer` is an uninitialised pointer; you have not allocated any memory.

Comment: don't forget the `\n` at the end of the `printf` format string.

Comment: @JensGustedt Should I always use a \n at the end of a format string ?(I am a beginner and have very little programming experience in C . )

Comment: @NikunjBanka Not always, but usually. As a rule, you will know when you do _not_ want a newline to end the output; if you are not sure that you don't want one, use a newline.

Comment: Which book are you reading? You need to make pointer point to something, before you can change the value of that something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

replace this

```
*pointer = num;
```

by

```
pointer = &num;
```

Your pointer should be pointed to a memory space before assignment of value to it.

When you define pointer in this way:

```
int *pointer;
```

This meas that you have defined pointer but the pointer is not yet pointing to a memory space. And if you use the pointer directly without pointing it to a memory space (like you did in your code) then you will get **undefined behaviour**.

pointing the pointer to amemory space could be done by one of the following way:

1) pointing to a static memory

```
int num;
int *pointer = &num;
```

num is an int defined as a static. So the pointer could be pointed to the num memory

2) pointing to a dynamic memory

```
int *pointer = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

the pointer could be pointed to a dynamic memory. the dynamic memory could be allocated with `malloc()` and when the memory became useless we can free memory with `free(pointer)`

Comment: It's a bit unfortunate to differentiate between dynamic and static memory the way you did, since `static` is a storage class specifier, and `num` has automatic storage. I'm not sure how to express it better, though.

Answer (score 1):

Assign address of num to pointer as pointer is supposed to hold address not value. You can read more about pointers [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/)

```
pointer = &num;
```

Change value of variable through pointer

```
*pointer = 11;
```

Answer (score 1):

First,you have defined a pointer by "int *pointer".

Then, you try to use "*pointer = num" to realize indirect access —— assign num's value to the memory space which the pointer "pointer" has pointed to.

OK, here is the problem! From your codes, you only have defined a pointer, but you have not made it pointed to a memory space. Making indirect access without doing it is very dangerous. So, you see the runtime error.

Now, you should add "int value;pointer = &value;" to your codes. It will make the pointer "pointer" point to "value". And you can assign "num" to "value" through indirect access "*pointer = num".

In my opinion, you should distinguish definition and indirect access when you study pointer.

I'm a person with poor English. This is my first answer in stack overflow. I hope that my answer can help you. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

First of all u should initialize the pointer as to which its trying to point then use it to modify the pointed value..as...

```
pointer=&num;
```

now use the pointer to change or access the value to which its pointing.